# How to set color for linum in emacs?

Tags: emacs

I am running emacs23-nox under Ubuntu12.04. How can I set font color for line numbers? They appear to be green by default, which I hate.

Thanks!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
(set-face-foreground 'linum "your-favorite-color")
```

Comment: Glad I could help. BTW why not switch to latest emacs release (24.3) as of now.

Comment: LOL I'm not any hard-core emacs'er, but just writing some tiny programs with a usable editor. I guess those new features won't matter to me.

Comment: This now seems to be `'line-number` rather than `'linum` (tested in Emacs 27)